# Webpacker can't find application.js in manifest.json Heroku Production

Tags: heroku, webpack

I'm having a webpacker issue with my app on heroku.

The log:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Webpacker can't find application.js in /app/public/packs/manifest.json. Possible causes:
2018-07-04T18:47:08.192729+00:00 app[web.1]: 1. You want to set webpacker.yml value of compile to true for your environment
2018-07-04T18:47:08.192730+00:00 app[web.1]:    unless you are using the `webpack -w` or the webpack-dev-server.
2018-07-04T18:47:08.192733+00:00 app[web.1]: 2. webpack has not yet re-run to reflect updates.
2018-07-04T18:47:08.192734+00:00 app[web.1]: 3. You have misconfigured Webpacker's config/webpacker.yml file.
2018-07-04T18:47:08.192735+00:00 app[web.1]: 4. Your webpack configuration is not creating a manifest.
2018-07-04T18:47:08.192737+00:00 app[web.1]: Your manifest contains:
2018-07-04T18:47:08.192738+00:00 app[web.1]: {
2018-07-04T18:47:08.192740+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2018-07-04T18:47:08.192741+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
```

I have a `manifest.json` file which does contain `application.js`:

```
{
  "application.css": "/packs/application-c922057d6b9db34084d6e52c6f32baa9.css",
  "application.css.map": "/packs/application-c922057d6b9db34084d6e52c6f32baa9.css.map",
  "application.js": "/packs/application-ab33c1479403810d7775.js",
  "application.js.map": "/packs/application-ab33c1479403810d7775.js.map"
}
```

It's interesting the final line in the log:

```
2018-07-04T18:47:08.192737+00:00 app[web.1]: Your manifest contains:
2018-07-04T18:47:08.192738+00:00 app[web.1]: {
2018-07-04T18:47:08.192740+00:00 app[web.1]: }
```

Is the formatting in the json wrong somehow?

I've tried running `bundle exec rails webpacker:compile` which was fine, and I've also updated the binstub `bundle exec rails webpacker:binstubs`, neither seem to have made a difference after pushing to Heroku.

What else can I try?

Answer (score 11):

- I removed folder `node_modules`
- then on terminal `yarn add @rails/webpacker@next`
- then `bundle exec rails webpacker:install`

after that, it's fixed

Comment: I tried many things, really... many things, but this one worked for me

Comment: My hero!!! If you're ever in Vancouver I'm taking you out to lunch.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Hany you have four lunches waiting for you in Vancouver. It's worth the trip!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and spent days trying to solve it. Finally installed webpacker 3.5 and works fine.

It is not the best solution but that gets my app up. I went on a rabbit hole trying solve this issue.

Comment: A year later your response continues to be the valid one unfortunately. I had to update from 3.5 to 4.0 for it to work, after multiple days and several failed attempts to fix this issue. Still no clue what was causing it but works now.

Comment: what a mess, on webpack 6 now so this is obsolete. funny thing is it's happened before and I've fixed it.. then it happened again(!!). webpack(er) needs removing from the internet.

Answer (score 2):

```
bundle exec bin/webpack-dev-server
```

this command solved my issue. I'm new to webpack, so I don't know how / why.

Comment: Running the dev-server on production is not really what you want.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are still stuck with this, I was having exactly the same problem and no other answers seemed to solve it for me. This GH thread advised ensuring that assets weren't precompiled locally (by removing `/public/assets` and `/public/packs` directories, essentially encouraging Heroku to compile for itself. Seems to have cleared up the issue for me for now.

https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/532

Comment: If you do that, precompiling assets would be failed and it won't be deployed on Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the exact same error. Try this if you have not yet.

run `bundle exec rails webpacker:install`

check console logs for the error message

```
The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">= 10.13.0". Got "10.0.0"
error Found incompatible module.
```

if yes, then you can resolve this issue in 3 steps:

`$ node -v`  checks your node version

`$ nvm install 'required node version'` changes the node version

`$ bundle exec rails webpacker:install` It will validate your package.json, resolve and fetch all the packages, link and save dependencies

Answer (score 0):

In my case below steps helped for newly added pack file  that was not found by webpacker

```
RAILS_ENV=staging rake  assets:clean

rake assets:clobber

RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile
```